# External microphone, with windows 10, says "Not Connected"

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, microphone, recording

I have a `Pioneer DM-DV20`, It's my first microphone, I would like to record sounds with this mic connected to my Windows 10 laptop.

My laptop is a `HP Pavilion 15` it has only a `Realtek` driver with one headphone jack like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6TwG.jpg).

Now, I have jack splitter wich looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZOPl.png), except that the rings on the jack are black.

When I connect the jack splitter to my computer, the `Sound -> Recording` menu [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PSHH.png) that the mic is connected (the selected mic) (although I just connect the splitter and nothing else).

When I plug in the `Pioneer DM-DV20` microphone to the jack splitters microphone part (rose red), it instantly shows "Not Connected", like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnVTd.png).

Therefore I cannot use the microphone, I have tried it in Audacity but it uses the inner mic of the laptop.

Also I have tried to plug the jack splitter + mic combo to my iPhone 7, but it didn't work at all. The only way I know that the mic is working is that I pluged it in one of my old laptops wich has a separate microphone port, It worked perfectly (both under Windows 10 and Windows 7).

Note that the microphone has an XLR connector with a 3.5 mm jack on it's end, thats what I used for these "tests".

**What I've tried:**

- Realtek driver update.
- Realtek driver removal.
- Getting Realtek HD Audio Manager on my laptop. (I still have none)
- Windows privacy settings. (Everything can use mic, I haven't changed that)
- Puting a headphone into the output part of the jack splitter while the mic part is connected to the mic. (No success, still using the inner mic of the laptop)

How can I make this microphone to work with my computer? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The splitter you have isn't for those type of microphones. They are used with old desktop mics that separated (split) mics and speakers. Have you tried hooking up the mic to.the laptop straight up?

Comment: Does the same, It says "Not Connected"

Comment: When you tried audacity did you try changing the audio input device?

Comment: I tried every device in the list, all of them were recording on the internal mic. Btw, what jack splitter should I use then?

Comment: https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/SC4--rode-sc4-adapter-female-3.5mm-trs-to-angled-3.5mm-trrs?&mrkgcl=28&mrkgadid=3274408772&product_id=SC4&campaigntype=shopping&campaign=aaShopping%2520-%2520Core%2520-%2520Accessories&adgroup=Accessories%2520-%2520Cables&placement=google&creative=249895767051&device=m&matchtype=&network=g&gclid=Cj0KCQiApaXxBRDNARIsAGFdaB-mZALGVmCqWMEFGIUtEGwq3z-7sqLtTvG4Qb_-yMPG0VlSrDgRWvUaAlzYEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: I have this kind of jack, are you sure?: https://assets.mmsrg.com/isr/166325/c1/-/pixelboxx-mss-74614105/mobile_580_430_png/PIONEER-DM-DV20-mikrofon

Comment:  trust, there's a difference